# Implement Aria 1.1

Tags: wai-aria

I am trying to implement the example 1 provided by w3c.org. The URL is https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/listbox-combo.html. It keeps giving me aria undefined error on line (var ex1Combobox = new aria.ListboxCombobox). Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label for="ex1-input"
  id="ex1-label"
  class="combobox-label">
Choice 1 Fruit or Vegetable
</label>
<div class="combobox-wrapper">
<div role="combobox"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-owns="ex1-listbox"
  aria-haspopup="listbox"
  id="ex1-combobox">
<input type="text"
      aria-autocomplete="list"
      aria-controls="ex1-listbox"
      id="ex1-input">
</div>
<ul aria-labelledby="ex1-label"
 role="listbox"
 id="ex1-listbox"
 class="listbox hidden">
</ul>
</div>

<script>
/*
*   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
*   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
*
* ARIA Combobox Examples
*/

var FRUITS_AND_VEGGIES = [
  'Apple',
  'Artichoke',
  'Asparagus',
  'Banana',
  'Beets',
  'Bell pepper',
  'Broccoli',
  'Brussels sprout',
  'Cabbage',
  'Carrot',
  'Cauliflower',
  'Celery',
  'Chard',
  'Chicory',
  'Corn',
  'Cucumber',
  'Daikon',
  'Date',
  'Edamame',
  'Eggplant',
  'Elderberry',
  'Fennel',
  'Fig',
  'Garlic',
  'Grape',
  'Honeydew melon',
  'Iceberg lettuce',
  'Jerusalem artichoke',
  'Kale',
  'Kiwi',
  'Leek',
  'Lemon',
  'Mango',
  'Mangosteen',
  'Melon',
  'Mushroom',
  'Nectarine',
  'Okra',
  'Olive',
  'Onion',
  'Orange',
  'Parship',
  'Pea',
  'Pear',
  'Pineapple',
  'Potato',
  'Pumpkin',
  'Quince',
  'Radish',
  'Rhubarb',
  'Shallot',
  'Spinach',
  'Squash',
  'Strawberry',
  'Sweet potato',
  'Tomato',
  'Turnip',
  'Ugli fruit',
  'Victoria plum',
  'Watercress',
  'Watermelon',
  'Yam',
  'Zucchini'
];

function searchVeggies (searchString) {
  var results = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < FRUITS_AND_VEGGIES.length; i++) {
    var veggie = FRUITS_AND_VEGGIES[i].toLowerCase();
    if (veggie.indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) === 0) {
      results.push(FRUITS_AND_VEGGIES[i]);
    }
  }

  return results;
}

/**
 * @function onload
 * @desc Initialize the combobox examples once the page has loaded
 */
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var ex1Combobox = new aria.ListboxCombobox(
    document.getElementById('ex1-combobox'),
    document.getElementById('ex1-input'),
    document.getElementById('ex1-listbox'),
    searchVeggies,
    false
  );

  var ex2Combobox = new aria.ListboxCombobox(
    document.getElementById('ex2-combobox'),
    document.getElementById('ex2-input'),
    document.getElementById('ex2-listbox'),
    searchVeggies,
    true
  );

  var ex3Combobox = new aria.ListboxCombobox(
    document.getElementById('ex3-combobox'),
    document.getElementById('ex3-input'),
    document.getElementById('ex3-listbox'),
    searchVeggies,
    true,
    function () {
      // on show
      document.getElementById('ex3-combobox-arrow')
        .setAttribute('aria-label', 'Hide vegetable options');
    },
    function () {
      // on hide
      document.getElementById('ex3-combobox-arrow')
        .setAttribute('aria-label', 'Show vegetable options');
    }
  );

  document.getElementById('ex3-combobox-arrow').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function () {
      if (ex3Combobox.shown) {
        document.getElementById('ex3-input').focus();
        ex3Combobox.hideListbox();
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById('ex3-input').focus();
        ex3Combobox.updateResults(true);
      }
    }
  );
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old post, but I have determined why the undefined error is occurring:
There are two js files associated with this example:
ListBox-Combox.js &
ListBox-Combo-example.js
The 'ListBox-Combo-example.js' file has event listeners for all three examples on the page
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/listbox-combo.html.
Since you only copied the code for the first example, when the javascript attempts to find the combobox 'ex2-Combobox' it cannot find it so javascript throws an error.
You can comment out these lines in the 'ListBox-Combo-example.js' file:

```
);
var ex2Combobox = new aria.ListboxCombobox(
  document.getElementById('ex2-combobox'),
  document.getElementById('ex2-input'),
  document.getElementById('ex2-listbox'),
  searchVeggies,
  true
);

var ex3Combobox = new aria.ListboxCombobox(
  document.getElementById('ex3-combobox'),
  document.getElementById('ex3-input'),
  document.getElementById('ex3-listbox'),
  searchVeggies,
  true,
```

and replace with a comma.  That should solve the problem.